# Use jPlayer in wordpress to play different files from different urls

Tags: wordpress, audio, jplayer

In a wordpress project I want to add [jplayer](http://jplayer.org/) to play audio files. So as I have used custom post type and for each post there will be different numbers of audio and different audio for every post. For adding audio urls I have used ACF plugin. Now can someone tell me how to use jPlayer to play each audio files without any issue. Because as I know jPlayer plays get the source in its js file like this

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
    wmode: "window",
    keyEnabled: true
});
```

So how to use different urls for the audio from the different urls.
Any help and suggestions wil be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can print the script inline in footer of the theme with a code like this:

```
function myplugin_jplayer_script() {
    global $post;
    $key = 'your_key';
    $id = 'your_id';
    $playlist = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, false);;
    $out = '';
    $out .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
    if( $playlist ) {
        $out .= 'var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("' . $id . '", {';
            foreach($playlist as $file){
                $out .= 'm4a: "'. $file .'",';
            }
        $out .= '}, {
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
            swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
            wmode: "window",
            keyEnabled: true
        });';
    }
    $out .= '</script>';
    return $out;
}
```

I have not proved this code, maybe is not completely correct, but you can get the idea. Extracted and modified from this plugin: https://github.com/audiolab/JPlayer-Wordpress-Plugin/blob/master/jplayer/jplayer.php